# How can I change print quality?

Tags: drivers, printing, epson, quality

I would like to use my Epson EcoTank L3110 printer. I have successfully installed the necessary drivers, and now, I can print, but I am not satisfied with the settings options. I can't change printer quality (only Plain Paper-Standard and Envelope-Standard available), and paper type (matte, glossy, normal paper, photo paper etc.) neither, hower when I use Windows, these options are available. I think it's a driver prblem.

How can I change printer quality?

[image: There are only TWO print quality options]

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution?